# Accessing linux mount location on windows through jenkins

Tags: windows, ubuntu, jenkins, mount, samba

I have path `/opt/test/share` mounted on ubuntu and shared with everyone using samba.
I have mapped Z: drive on windows to above path.

Now, If I do `cd Z:/` and then `dir` from local windows box, it works fine.
But if I try to do same thing through jenkins it says "The system cannot find the path specified"

Please help.

Comment: What version of command prompt are you using? `cd Z:/` is never a valid command. To change a drive, you use just `Z:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is Jenkins running on the Windows machine as you or as a Windows Service?  Mounting in Windows is user-dependent.

If you are running Jenkins as a Service on Windows, you will need to explicitly tell "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" account to mount the drive.  The page "[How to map network shares into drives to a Windows service permanently](https://support.asperasoft.com/entries/23290747-How-to-map-network-shares-into-drives-to-a-Windows-service-permanently)" should help you set up the mount.

**Update 2021 Oct:** Since the above link is broken I am adding a new link for reference:
[How to map network shares into drives to a Windows service permanently](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-map-network-shares-drives-windows-service-permanently)

Comment: Jenkins is running as windows service.