# MSBUILD plugin for Jenkins doesn't see the SUBST drive

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I have Jenkins building for me using the MSBUILD plugin. But the solution is on a SUBST drive. I always get

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: X:\example.sln

When Jenkins builds not using the SUBST X drive it works. Or if I manually build from the X: drive it works. Not sure why I cannot get the MSBUILD to work with the SUBST drive. Jenkins has all read/write privileges.

---

I appreciate y'all taking the time to help me with this. I finally found the solution. It was Jenkins that couldn't see it. I found it at /questions/24733917/jenkins-cant-see-mapped-drive on this website. Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: I've done that awhile back to get shorter paths. Try restarting the Jenkins service after creating the drive. Another idea, run SUBST from MSBUILD  during the job.

Comment: Try narrowing down the problem, e.g. does `dir x:` or `dir x:\example.sln` work from jenkins?

Comment: @TomBlodget Thank you for the tip. I restarted the service after creating the drive. Still nothing. Unfortunately I can't create the drive during the job because the exe that creates the drive is GUI only, no command arguments. Bit of a pain in the neck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins can't see mapped drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733917/jenkins-cant-see-mapped-drive)